# Passing/recieving strings through a C interface on a C++ software

Tags: c++, c, dll, interface

I'm not familliar with C, but I have to write a C interface for my C++ software to deliver it as a dynamic library. In term of *classical practices*, I have two questions:

1. What are the classical ways to pass and recieve strings and who has the memory responsibility ?
2. Is it a good idea to always reserve the return value for error code and then recieve values with pointers in arguments ? If not, why ?

Here is an example illustrating my questions with code I firstly imagine:

```
int define_new_population(int* id)
{
  // all_pop is a std::map<int,std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Element>>>
  *id = generate_id();
  all_pop[*id] = std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Element>>();
  return 0;
}

int add_element_type1_in_pop(int pop_id, const char* name, double lower_bound, double upper_bound)
{
  if(all_pop.find(pop_id) == all_pop.end())
    return ERROR_CODE_WRONG_ID;
  const std::string str_name(name);
  try { all_pop[pop_id].push_back(boost::shared_ptr<Element>(new ElementType1(str_name, lower_bound, upper_bound))); }
  catch(...) { return ERROR_CODE_FOO; }
  return 0;
}

int add_element_type2_in_pop(int pop_id, const char* name, double reference)
{
  if(all_pop.find(pop_id) == all_pop.end())
    return ERROR_CODE_WRONG_ID;
  const std::string str_name(name);
  try { all_pop[pop_id].push_back(boost::shared_ptr<Element>(new ElementType2(str_name, reference))); }
  catch(...) { return ERROR_CODE_BAR; }
  return 0;
}

int get_population_size(int pop_id, int* pop_size)
{
  if(all_pop.find(pop_id) == all_pop.end())
    return ERROR_CODE_WRONG_ID;
  *pop_size = (int)all_pop[pop_id].size();
  return 0;
}

int get_element_name(int pop_id, int elem_index, char** name)
{
  if(all_pop.find(pop_id) == all_pop.end())
    return ERROR_CODE_WRONG_ID;
  if(elem_index >= (int)all_pop[pop_id].size())
    return ERROR_CODE_OUT_OF_RANGE;
  const std::string& str_name = all_pop[pop_id][elem_index].getName();
  *name = malloc(sizeof(char) * (str_name.length() + 1));
  strcpy(*name, str_name.c_str());
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*name = malloc(sizeof(char) * (str_name.length() + 1));` your dynamic library allocated the memory, it is up to your library to free it.  You will need to provide a function to do this.  The application and shared library do not necessarily share the same runtime support and heap.  So they can't allocate and free each others memory.

Comment: Addition (discussion): about half of the MS-Windows API requires the caller to pre-allocate a buffer and pass a pointer and size to the API (can return buffer not big enough error and required size).  In this case the caller is responsible for freeing the memory.  The other times the MS-Windows API allocates the buffer for the API call and provides a free-memory call for the caller to use when it's finished with the memory.

Comment: I believe the caller should be responsible for memory management.

Comment: As Richard Critten says your dynamic library allocated the memory, it is up to your library to free it. But most of the time that is impossible. What you should do there is provide a function to free the memory and document that the application has to call this function to free the memory.

Comment: A function like `define_new_population` that always returns 0 generally makes no sense. It can't fail so don't return an error code. -- In this case though you failed to catch std::bad_alloc and return an appropriate error code.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: the implementation of the function could change after some revisions. If it's the case, it changes the interface, and then impact the user of the library. I prefer to have a function that always-for-the-moment returns 0 in order to be able to refactor it with error management.

Answer (score 2):

I can at least give some advice.

- Who frees the memory (caller or DLL) should be clearly defined in the API.
- Be aware that if caller and callee are compiled separately with different versions of the Windows std C library, malloc and free by different versions of the C lib/runtime will in general not work. If you can automate this by giving the API user a 'memory free' callback that can be used with RAII, this is a good way. Give API user simple examples to follow.
- If you have full control over both DLL lib and caller, you can even pass C++ exceptions over DLL boundaries, much cleaner than error codes, but if you do not know exactly what you do, more fragile.
- You can even have a C++ (not pure C) api, using window's/Visual Studio 'it just works' mechanism. It just works and even extends to C++/CLI and C# mixed codebases. Here is some more documentation: [implicit PInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x8kf7zx.aspx)

As for the question about reserving return value for error codes and sending in pointers (or if necessary, pointers to pointers), that is usually good and a very general technique. Of course, if you make a C++ API, the modern way is to make use of perfect forwarding and rvalue references instead.